# Pandas: How do I convert a custom date format to datetime (different locale)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a `Date` column in format "Jan 20, 2019" or "Feb 01, 2019". This is of course, english. But my locale is spanish (ES), I think it must be something with the locale, because if I do

```
pd.to_datetime('Feb 01, 2019', format='%b %m, %Y')
```

it works, I believe is because February (Feb) is the same as Febrero (Feb), but if I do

```
pd.to_datetime('Jan 01, 2019', format='%b %m, %Y')
```

I think that's because January (Jan) is different from Enero (Ene), so before my processing I did:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'EN')
```

But it's not working either. I'm pretty sure my format string is okay, but I'm not completely sure. Should I have to "translate" components into something easier to understand like %m/%d/%Y?

Comment: Can you show us what the output is from each of your attempts?

Comment: It was an embarrasing mistake. Anyway the output didn't say that much, the error was `ValueError: time data 'Jan 31, 2019' does not match format '%b %m, %Y' (match)`

Comment: Stuff like this happens to every programmer. Next time, showing the exact input and output in the question will help. Notice that `'Jan 01, 2019'` actually doesn't raise an error (because `01` is a valid month) while `'Jan 31, 2019'` does (because `31` isn't a valid month).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your format string [is wrong](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.strftime.html). You want `%d` (day as a decimal number), not `%m` (month as a decimal number):

```
pd.to_datetime('Jan 01, 2019', format='%b %d, %Y')
```

Comment: Oh damn... I feel so stupid, of course %m is month and that space is day %d

Comment: Should I delete the question? It's embarrasing!